# Prometheus cannot find Django /metrics

Tags: django, prometheus, django-prometheus

Im using the prometheus client library for Django. I am not running prometheus in a Docker container. The Djanog application is bound to Unix domain sockets, so I think that is part of my issue but idk how to resolve. NGINX is listening on port 80 and re-routes traffic with the `proxy_pass` header. I dont understand how my node_exporter (server metrics) works fine with the local host target, but my application will not. Even from a browser I can access "/metrics" endpoint. I've tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, and even the server IP and nothing works. Also, IPtables has nothing related to port 80, yet I've created a "denied" log record and Im getting "... src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 dpt=80 [...]"

NGINX

```
erver {
    server_name hotname www.hostname ip;

[...]


    location /metrics{

        proxy_pass http://<unix_domain>;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:<location_of_domain_socket>;
        }
```

prometheus

```
<default prom config>
[...]
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "django-app"
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost] # nothing works and prometheus attempts to use port 80 with a predefined scheme of http://

  - job_name: "node"
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9100"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the 100% solutions, but I just used the TCP/IP that  Gunicorn uses by default, changed the target location in the Prometheus config to localhost:8000 (default TCP/IP address) and it works as expected